# Resize /dev/sda in virtual box

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using rhel 7.3 on virtual box.
The software I am trying to install requires 1000 M available swap.
Can someone explain to me how can I change that ?

[image]

Comment: The program won't accept more ram, instead of more swap? Ram can be changed in VirtualBox's settings easily. What program is it?

Comment: Resolved the issue by reinstalling linux and manually configurating swap.